# Is hiding GET parameters by rewriting it to POST and redirect a good idea?

Tags: php, post, redirect, get

I want to hide parameters from URL. I'm using **uuids** instead of **ids** and when I pass it in URL it looks a bit long and ugly. First thought was to use little forms with hidden inputs istead of anchors, but it will be uncomfortable to replace every one anchor with form, also it will not work when an anchor is placed in another form already.

So second thought was rewriting `$_GET` to `$_POST`/`$_SESSION` and then redirect again to this script. All variables will be available and the URL will be clean and short.

But what with performance of this solution? Is it a good idea to do it this way?

Any help or other ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS.

Comment: If you just care for the "beauty" of the url, put your app in a frame. This also helps against users bookmarking an URL with GET parameters

Comment: UIDs are fine inside forms, but do you want to pass them from page to page? If so, they'll need to go in hyperlinks, and so you'd need to put them in GET strings from time to time - unless you use something like postbacks (which imo are clunky). Could you maybe put this thing in the session instead? (It's difficult to know what to suggest to do when we don't know what it is or what it is for).

Comment: @Eugen Please do not revert time back to Web 0.8. Frames are an anti-pattern. Understand HTTP and use it wisely, don't try to work around it.

Comment: You can't post over a redirect - it'll just turn into a GET anyways.

Comment: $_REQUEST can handle both POST and GET

Comment: @deceze Yes, frame is not acceptable ;)

Comment: @deceze I beg to disagree: Yes, frames (as in plural) are an anti-pattern. No, a frame (as in singular) with no logic in it and only used as a GET-URL-hider is **not** an anti-pattern. It is the simplest solution to the "User bookmarks URL with session-id" problem.

Comment: @Eugen 1) Session ids in the URL should be avoided. In this day and age they're obsolete, cookies can reasonably be expected to be supported; use them. 2) This question is not about session ids in the URL. 3) Because people cannot bookmark these pages is exactly the reason why any form of frames should be avoided. If you need them to hide session ids, see 1).

Comment: @deceze Again I disagree: 1.) Session cookies are evil. Let's just agree to disagree on that. 2.) This question is about the "beauty" of an URL - session ids are the textbook example of that 3.) Thanks for validating my argument! If you don't **want** people to bookmark the page, doing something to make it harder is the way to go.

Comment: @Eugen Yeah, we'll have to disagree on that. Let's say I prefer to keep my sites usable, which includes letting people bookmark them.

Comment: @deceze It's sad, that you are unable to understand, that very often you don't want a user to bookmark a special page (as it might not exist in another session), but the corresponding landing page. Maybe I am simply unable to explain it.

Comment: @Eugen It's you saying that I'm not able to understand that. I'm saying that you should understand and use the HTTP protocol properly, in which case there shouldn't be a "special page that might not exist in another session" to begin with. Each GET request should be self-contained in the URL and idempotent, period. If there are temporary pages, like nonce tokens etc, the response should redirect, so the page isn't bookmarkable to begin with.

Comment: @deceze Sorry for the "not able to understand", I am non-english native and I explicitly said it was my not being able to explain it. Let me give you an example: http://somethi.ng?action=show&id=1234 might be a perfectly fine URL, that you don't want your user to bookmark - because he will get "access denied" every time he opens the bookmark, as he is not logged in. Is it "keep my sites usable" to allow him to bookmark this? It might be a bad idea to frame it on a public site, but it will result in literally hundreds of support calls, if inhouse apps are bookmarked this way.

Comment: @Eugen Of course there's a standard solution to that as well: User requests `/foo?id=42`, response redirects user to `/login`, message displays *Please log in to view the requested resource*, user logs in and is redirected back to `/foo?id=42`. Boom, best of both worlds. If you still need to intentionally cripple your app because your users cannot understand this simple mechanism, I feel really sorry for you. :)

Comment: Seems we just have to agree to disagree - I don't want you to feel sorry for me on such a beautiful winter weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change GET to POST or vice versa for *prettiness*. Both HTTP methods are handled very differently in many contexts, and you don't want to cause these kind of side effects.

POST requests cannot be self-contained in a URL, i.e. try to send someone the link to a site that requires a POST request. POST requests screw with browser history, i.e. try clicking the back button to go back to a page submitted via POST. POST requests aren't indexed by search engines.

POST requests are supposed to be used to *modify* data on the server. Don't use them for all regular requests.

If you need prettier URLs, find some other way to reference your records. Or just stop caring about it, it's really not *that* important.

Comment: It's sounds reasonably, especially because I will sent mails with URLs to the users. Also back button issue sounds bad with my solution. I think it is the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you will of course loose ALL search engine benefits across the entire width of your site if you universaly adopt this strategy. you should only *really* use `$_POST` when you are submitting data that needs to be saved to a storage medium (or where you are sending secure data https etc), otherwise the recommendation is `$_GET` for 'requested' data. So, you'll need to identify the use case here and follow that pattern.

I understand what you are saying about 'ugly' URLs, but would advise you to be cautious on looking for remedial action on this. One way of course would be to do a urlrewrite on the incoming parameters but this would require database lookups etc (to get the mapped nice url string), so could be costly.

I'll get back with any other thoughts as they occur.

Comment: Search engine is not that important, but you and @deceze are right, lets GET do its work and POST its.